# In OfficeScript, how can I make it return the number of cells with a red background?

Tags: excel, office365, office-scripts

I developed the script, but it always returns a value of 0, why?

I'm looking for the cells that have a red background and adding them all together and returning the total amount located.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {     
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();        
  const targetColor = "#FF0000";      
  let foundCellCount = 0;      
  let columnARange = selectedSheet.getRange("A:A");      
  let cellValues = columnARange.getValues(); 
  
  if (cellValues !== null) {       
    cellValues.forEach((row, index) => {          
      let cellBackgroundColor = columnARange.getCell(index, 0).getFormat().getFill();          
      if (cellBackgroundColor !== null) {           
        foundCellCount++;
      }
    });
  }          
  console.log(`Total is ${targetColor}: ${foundCellCount}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `.getColor()` to get the value of filling color
- The `if cluase` should be `if (cellBackgroundColor === targetColor)`
- Use `getUsedRange().getColumn(0)` to get the used cells on Col A
- `if (cellValues !== null)` can be simplified as `if (cellValues)`

```vb
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    const targetColor = "#FF0000";
    let foundCellCount = 0;
    let columnARange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange().getColumn(0);
    let cellValues = columnARange.getValues();
    if (cellValues) {
        cellValues.forEach((row, index) => {
            let cellBackgroundColor = 
            columnARange.getCell(index, 0).getFormat().getFill().getColor();
            if (cellBackgroundColor === targetColor) {
                foundCellCount++;
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(`Total is ${targetColor}: ${foundCellCount}`);
}
```